# how to combine two levels in one categorical variable in R

Tags: r

I am now learning R, and I have problem with finding a command.

I have the categorical data

```
levels(job)
[1] "admin."        "blue-collar"   "entrepreneur"  "housemaid"    
[5] "management"    "retired"       "self-employed" "services"     
[9] "student"       "technician"    "unemployed"    "unknown"
```

now I want to simplify these levels, such as

```
levels(job) 
[1] "class1"  "class2" "class3" "unknown"
```

where `type1` includes `"admin."`, `"entrepreneur"`, and `"self-employed"`;
  `type2` includes `"blue-collar"`,`"management"`, and `"technician"`;
  `type3` includes `"housemaid"`, `"student"`, `"retired"`, and `"services"`;
  `unknown` includes `"unknown"` and `"unemployed"`.

For this purpose, which command can I use? 
Thanks!
 Yan

Answer (score 11):

You can assign to `levels`:

```
levels(z)[levels(z)%in%c("unemployed","unknown","self-employed")] <- "unknown"
```

This is covered in the help file -- type `?levels`.

---

Stealing from @akrun's answer, you could do this most cleanly with a hash/list:

```
ha <- list(
  unknown = c("unemployed","unknown","self-employed"),
  class1  = c("admin.","management")
)

for (i in 1:length(ha)) levels(z)[levels(z)%in%ha[[i]]] <- names(ha)[i]
```

Answer (score 4):

You may also create an 'key/value' index vector and use that to replace the elements in 'job'

```
indx <-  setNames(rep(c(paste0('type',1:3), 'unknown'), c(3,3,4,2)), 
      c(levels(job)[c(1,3,7)], levels(job)[c(2,5,10)], 
      levels(job)[c(4,6,8,9)], levels(job)[c(11,12)]))

factor(unname(indx[as.character(job)]))
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c('admin.', 'blue-collar', 'entrepreneur', 'housemaid',
'management', 'retired', 'self-employed', 'services', 'student', 
'technician', 'unemployed', 'unknown')
set.seed(24)
job <- factor(sample(v1, 50, replace=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the `recode` function from the `car` package.

(Posting as answer rather than comment, will delete if someone else posts a better answer)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, base-r solution : create a `character` vector, change its values, `factor()` it.

```
job <- as.character(job)
job[job %in% c("admin.","entrepreneur","self-employed")] <- "class1"
... # do the same for the other classes
job <- factor(job)
```

Another solution is `irec()` in the package `questionr`. It opens a shiny app in your browser that allows interactive recoding, and then outputs the proper code in the console.